# How do I get hold of my CodeContext in IronPython RC1?

Tags: .net, hosting, ironpython

[CodeContext](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/59952?projectName=IronPython#992911) is used throughout IronPython. But since I moved to IronPython RC1 I cannot get hold of one.

Has anyone used IronPython RC1 and managed to use

```
ClrModule.AddReferenceByName(...)
```

or

```
PythonType.__getattribute__(...)
```

Both of them take a CodeContext and hence I can no longer use them.

Answer (score 2):

To get a hold of a CodeContext create a ModuleContext just like you used to craete a CodeContext.  Then just access the GlobalContext property to get the CodeContext.

Comment: I did this. I built a ModuleContext and then built a CodeContext from it but I'm sure this is not the correct approach. I assume I should be getting the CodeContext from the CompiledCode which represents the code I'd like to run. 

I'll post more here once I get back round to this. In the mean time I've gone back to Beta 2

Answer (score 0):

Just call these functions via 'eval' then.

Comment: It's an interesting idea and might work for the clr.AddRef piece. But I need to effectively reflect over python types from C# which I don't think would work well via eval() or Execute()

Comment: i am not sure how IronPython is laid out lately, but all modules (dlls) will have a static __global_context field. Else that failing, try using the InvariantContext, or try grab something from the ModuleContext.

Comment: Toplevel functions normally do not require a CodeContext as they contain no free variables, not sure why they have chosen this approach.